# How can I connect to mqtt server with socket io client?

Tags: flutter, dart, socket.io, mqtt

> I want to connect with mqtt server a socket io client. Is this possible? if possible how can i do it. Can you help me ?

Answer (score 1):

you can follow something like this

https://github.com/mcqn/mqtt-socketio-bridge

by creating mqtt bridge.